# Updating a specific list in a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, append

When I try to update a specific list in a list of lists, all the lists are updated. Can someone explain how instead only a specific list can be updated?

```
a = [[]]*55 
a[0].append(5)
```

Comment: You guys pushing hard to make that take the lead as the most-duplicated Python question...

Comment: S/O - prob. can consider FAQ list like this.  :-)  to save some energy/time.